# DataTables success callback alternative

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I'm trying to use DataTables with a success callback. Because I want to give a user a warning if the values they entered that creates a DataTable has an error.

Unfortunately, DataTables requires success callback for themselves, hence I cannot overload it.

Currently the code is:

```
configurationBlockChart = $('#blockSearchTable').DataTable(
{
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    stateSave: true,
    bDestroy: true,
    ajax: 
    {
        type: 'GET',
        url:"ajax_retreiveServerSideBlockNames/",
        data:
        {
            'csrfmiddlewaretoken':csrftoken,
            'username':username
        }
    },
    rowCallback: function(row, data)
    {
        if ($.inArray(data.DT_RowId, blockSelected)!== -1)
        {
            $(row).addClass('selected');
        }
    },
});
```

The data that is returned by this Ajax Get are rows of data.

However, there is a possibility that the data returned has a response of invalid, with no rows returned

I tried to add success before rowCallBack:

```
success: function(response)
{
     if(response.status == "invalid")
          //then inform user
}
```

Also tried to use fnDrawCallBack

```
fnDrawCallback: function(settings, response)
{
    console.log("Hello World!");
    if(response.status == "invalid")
    {
        $('#invalid').modal("show");
        $('#usernameSearch').modal("show");
    }
}
```

However, the fnDrawCallBack will only call if there are rows returned.

The problem is that sometimes that no rows are returned, and an exception is given by the javascript code.

I could, however, do a try catch, but I would still like my server to give json statuses to the javascript code.

EDIT: With using xhr, it could catch that invalid response while in the meantime does not interfere with the success function for ajax.

```
$('#chartSearchUsername').click(function(event)
{
    $('#chartConfigModal').modal("hide");
    $('#usernameSearch').modal("show");

    configurationUserChart = $('#userSearchTable').DataTable(
    {
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        stateSave: true,
        bDestroy: true,
        ajax: 
        {
            type: 'GET',
            url:"ajax_retreiveServerSideUsernames/",
            data:
            {
                'csrfmiddlewaretoken':csrftoken
            },
        },
        rowCallback: function(row, data)
        {
            if ($.inArray(data.DT_RowId, userSelected)!== -1)
            {
                $(row).addClass('selected');
            }
        },
    })
    .on('xhr.dt', function(e, settings, response)
    {
        if(response.status == "invalid")
        {
            $('#invalid').modal("show");
            $('#usernameSearch').modal("hide");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you tried moving the callback function to be executed on the xhr event? [Reference here](http://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax). Then you could check what's coming back first

Comment: Thanks for your response! No, I haven't tried that, I will look at the reference asap.

Comment: Nice! Glad to hear it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#example').dataTable();

$('#example').on( 'xhr.dt', function () {
    console.log( 'Ajax call finished' );
} );
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery datatables is coded to use the success callback in ajax and it breaks if you intercept it. [Source](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/109910/#Comment_109910)

You can also make use of [jQuery ajax **dataFilter** callback](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

```
$('table[id=entries]').DataTable({
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: {
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://example.com/entries',
        dataFilter: function(response) {
            var json_response = JSON.parse(response);
            if (json_response.recordsTotal) {
                // There're entries;
            }else{
                // There're no entries;
            }
            return response;
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            console.error(xhr.responseJSON);
        }
    }
});
```

**Note:** Return a *String*, not JSON in dataFilter callback.